# Possible encoding issue between PS and C++

Tags: c++, powershell

I have a C++ program written using Qt that I'm using as a front end to create AD accounts. Essentially I launch an elevated process that executes PowerShell commands within an elevated PowerShell session. I can create the accounts fine but when I attempt to pull membership from a pre-existing user to copy it over to the new one it fails. I need to understand why it's failing and resolve the issue, any help is greatly appreciated. It fails with the following error:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the
argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:2 char:28
+ "}); $groups = (Get-ADUser $tmpusr -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf; $u ...
+                            ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

The `$tmpusr` variable is just the value of `duser.template_user` which is pulled from a `QComboBox` and is deffinetly not null because it outputs correctly and shows the selected template account. In C++ it's just data added to a struct member:

```
duser.set_groups_command = "$tmpusr = (Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like " "\"" + duser.template_user + "\"" "}); "
                           "$groups = (Get-ADUser $tmpusr -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf; "
                           "$usr = " "\"" + duser.sam_name + "\"" + "; "
                           "Foreach ($group in $groups) {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity (Get-ADGroup $group).name -Members $usr} ";
```

If I strip the C++ and run the same command within PowerShell it executes fine:

```
$tmpusr = (Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like "Example User"}); $groups = (Get-ADUser $tmpusr -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf; $usr = "TestUser"; Foreach ($group in $groups) {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity (Get-ADGroup $group).name -Members $usr}
```

The purpose of the command is to determine which groups "Example User" belongs to and then to add "TestUser" to the same groups. Again, creating the user works fine. That is done with:

```
duser.complete_command = p + "New-ADUser -Name " + "\"" + duser.employe_name +"\"" + " -GivenName " + "\"" + duser.given_name + "\""
                + " -Surname " + "\"" + duser.surname + "\"" + " -AccountPassword $sec " + " -UserPrincipalName " + "\"" + duser.userpname + "\""
                " -DisplayName " + "\"" + duser.display_name + "\"" + " -EmailAddress " + "\"" + duser.email_address + "\"" + " -SamAccountName " +
                "\"" + duser.sam_name + "\"" + " -Enabled " + duser.is_enabled;
```

You'll note the existence of "p" which is another QString created earlier on to convert to a secure string. The only other component is the function that elevates and executes:

```
 void MainWindow::elevate_and_execute(QString param)
 {
     QProcess *process = new QProcess();
     QStringList params = QStringList();
     params = QStringList({"-Command", QString("Start-Process -Verb runAs powershell; "), param});
     process->startDetached("powershell", params);
     process->waitForFinished();
     process->terminate();

 }
```

Comment: It looks like to me that there are extra double quotes before some of your slashes?  Could you try a slimmer version of the same statement and see what happens?  `"$tmpusr = Get-ADUser -Filter \"Name -like '" + duser.template_user + "'\";"` which should essentially be the same as `$tmpusr = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like 'Example User'";`

Comment: The adittional quotes are just inteded to escape a single double quote where needed. so "\"" is really just " but there certainly are other ways of achieving this. I'll try the slimmed down version and see what happens, thank you!

Comment: @suroh Yes, but you are doing it like `"... " "\""` instead of `"... \""`.

Comment: I guess you are just missing some `+`s   `"... " "\""` should be `"... " + "\""`

Comment: Gotcha, yeah sorry I guess I had a little stroke there. Thank you both for pointing that out. I'm sorry for the delayed response, I tried the reduction but am having the same error in the same place. I'l lreview more thoroughly in case I've missed something else. Could the be an issue in how the commands are chained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. I found that when I pulled the so called template user from the `QComboBox` it contained a carriage return. I had written the logs to a text file and found it was pushing it to the next line; so the `$tmpusr` was broken. I was able to resolve the issue by modifying the `duser.template_user` variable when it's initially filled by stripping that `"\r"` out with `remove(QChar('\r'))`